# Creating new facebook apps with graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

To my knowledge it isn't possible to create new apps with the graph api from facebook.

But i have seen several tab makers which are apparently able to generate new apps (one of them is the timeline tab maker from 247GRAD). Is this huge number of apps really manually generated?

I would appreciate it very much if someone could give me a hint, how those apps work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to create an application using Graph API.

What you see in the case of [Page Tab Applications](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) is generally one application (or several just to have different application icons/images) displaying different content based on page id (from [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/#step1)) for Page is running on.

Comment: Hi Juicy! Thank you very much! Your hint is exactly what i've been looking for. Do you know any how to's which describe this matter? (delivering different content to different users inside an app) Greetings

Comment: @killersheep, I've added links to my answer which you may found useful to get started. It's really up to you how and what content you will display in the Page Tab, once you know the ID of the page Application is running on it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'll try to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Many companies are today oriented to design Facebook  apps (or tabs) to be integrated in profiles, groups and fan pages. Well Facebook encourages apps development by making easy to do with Graph API with any programming language like PHP5 at first, jQuery, JavaScript, Java, XML...

And Apps or tab makers as you said are developed to help to generate new apps, I think it would boring for a developer to create an app for form contact everyday for each new customer, so with some magic (sure with any programming language) he'll can generate many apps.

```
So it's a Facebook app that creates Facebook apps!
```

You could learn about Facebook Graph API from Facebook Developers Documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

And learn this tutorial from Facebook on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ or from an other web sites (Try always to read new tutorials because Facebook API always changes).

Also you can read books, I advice to read this at first : http://books.google.tn/books?id=MnbpygAACAAJ&dq=inauthor:%22Shashwat+Srivastava%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c5RoT81ek_fhBNXZgbcJ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA and second, http://books.google.tn/books?id=Ec9OkpsrCf8C&pg=PA131&dq=facebook+graph+api&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tpBoT5uKG-OO4gTb-ajaAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=facebook%20graph%20api&f=false

Don't hesitate to ask.

Best regards,
Ali

Comment: Hi Ali! Thanks for your answer! The resources you 've posted, especially those two books, will be very useful for me.